# can I inject DProvider in .Net 6 Web API program/startup class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have .Net 6 asp.net Web Api app where I have registered the interface `IDProvider` and concrete implementation `DProvider` in `Program` class. Now I want to call the method inside that interface within `Program` class, Is this possible?

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDProvider, DProvider>();

        var logConnectionString = await _dProvide.GetValue("abc");
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: how to call `IDProvider` method?

Comment: `builder.Services.GetService<IDProvider>();`